# How to dynamically generate a nested class in Python?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I have well know class and I need to dynamically generate some nested classes for the well known class.

How do I accomplish this?

```
def AddNestedClasses(cls):
    inner1  = type("Inner")
    # How do I inject the class 'Inner' into 'cls'?
    return cls

@AddNestedClasses
class Outer:
    pass
```

Comment: How about `setattr(cls, 'Inner', inner1)`? By the way, `type("Inner")` is always the class `str` - is that what you intended?

Comment: You could also do it using inheritance instead of a decorator.

Comment: What do you mean by a "well known" class? What would be a "not well known" class?

Comment: Thank you, that works. I changed the parameter passed to type to type("Inner", (), {}) to stop getting a string. And then I set the property 'Inner' as suggested above to 'inner1' and that worked. I dir the class and it has a nested class "Inner".

Answer (score 2):

```
def AddNestedClasses(cls):
    inner1  = type("Inner", (), {})
    cls.Inner = inner1
    return cls

@AddNestedClasses
class Outer:
    pass

print(dir(Outer))
```